XPATH for the descendant of an ancestor above of the current node
<oc-resume-upload>
    <div data-test="resume-upload-container" class="form-section">
        <div class="flex flex-column">
            <h2 class="form-section-header form-section-header--required"> **Resume **</h2>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div ocappdrag="" class="dropzone dropzone-upload">
                        <oc-file-upload-button _nghost-ng-c1329912542="">
                            <div _ngcontent-ng-c1329912542="">
                                **<button _ngcontent**-ng-c1329912542="" type="button" data-test="resume-upload" aria-label="Upload resume" class="padding--m button button--clean">
                                    <span class="font-size--s font--bold">
                                        <strong>Select file</strong>, or drop file here    
                                    </span>
                                </button> 

So basically my current node is the button _ ngcontent and I want to find the first Content (in type text) available in his ancestor or children of ancestors. In this case I would like to have the text of the h2 tag that has "Resume" as content.
'./ancestor::*[normalize-space(.//*)][1]'

This code allows to find text in any descendants of ancestors or ancestors but problem is, it also find my descendants. As such I get "Select File" from the  tag which i dont want.
./ancestor::*[normalize-space(string(.)) and not(self::*) and not(.//*)][1]

Should be the one working since I exclude my node and my node descendants but in this case I dont find anything ...

h2 is not an ancestor; maybe try preceding::...
./preceding::*[text()[normalize-space()]][1]

I'm not very familiar with selenium and its xpath support, and you don't show any python so I can't see how you're calling it, but the above is valid 1.0 xpath.
